# Inject domain service to entity Spring boot + Gradle

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, entity, aspectj

Trying to inject domain Service to Entity and getting NPE while calling it.
Using Spring Boot 3+ and Gradle. I hope its not the case that I need manually set plugins to enable Aspects. Tryed with no good result.

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Table(name = "usr")
@Configurable(preConstruction=true,dependencyCheck=true,autowire=Autowire.BY_TYPE)
public class User  {
  @Transient
  @Autowired
  private SomeService service;
  // ...
}
```

Application annotated with

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSpringConfigured
public class UserServiceApplication {
  // ...
}
```

Gradle shows that spring-aspects-6.0.11.jar is in the clip.
Since all annotations are imported from the box I assume that this dependencies would be enough

```java
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap'
```

Hope there is some elegant way Spring provides to make it work. Add some verbose configuration elements to force this injection is not a problem, except getting some verbose elements.

I kindly ask to leave aside the questions about the purpose of such injection. Since this can be done, a technical issue needs to be resolved.

[image: versions]

Comment: You need to setup loadtimeweaving for this to work and yes you need a javaagent for that. This is also explained in the spring (not spring boot!) reference guide.

Comment: @M.Deinum Used annotation `@EnableLoadTimeWeaving` but get BeanCreationException which suggest to make custom LoadTimeWeaver. Deaclaring a `@Bean` of new InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver dosen't help. Is there any way to make it as declarative as possible?

Comment: No you will need an agent just the annotation won't be enough as it will start instrumentation too late.

Comment: @M.Deinum So its necessary to make some building intervention through plugins or so?

Comment: No you need a javaagent when starting the application. SO it needs to be part of the application command.

Comment: @M.Deinum Ok I add VM option -javaagent: \\full-path-to\\spring-instrument-6.0.11.jar which get from `implementation group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-instrument', version: '6.0.11'(my Spring (not boot) actual version)
` as suggested in BeanCreationException message:`Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.instrument.classloading.LoadTimeWeaver]: ... Specify a custom LoadTimeWeaver or start your Java virtual machine with Spring's agent: -javaagent:spring-instrument-{version}.jar`
and get Totall mess with kilometers of stacktrace in a start. Seems like its not enough.

Comment: WIthout knowing what the errors/logging are that is impossible to answer.

Comment: @M.Deinum `jakarta.persistence.spi.TransformerException: Error performing enhancement of org/springframework/data/querydsl/SimpleEntityPathResolver
Caused by: net.bytebuddy.pool.TypePool$Resolution$NoSuchTypeException: Cannot resolve type description for com.querydsl.core.types.EntityPath
`
and aprx 12k of trase like  
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: module java.base does not open java.lang to unnamed module @8c3b9d

Comment: Looks like either some incompatible versions (you are now mixing Spring 6.0.11 and 6.0.8) and could be that the JDK isn't supported if it is too new. I also wonder why Jakarta is now trying to enhance things.

Comment: @M.Deinum From where 6.0.8 version appeared? I posted spring libs list screenshot for you. JDK is corretto-17 do you suggest that for this kind of injection modern java versions is no suitable?

Comment: That is what you stated **Graddle shows that spring-aspects-6.0.8.jar**.  So going with that and you adding 6.0.11 for instrumentation is mixing versions. Next to that the agent will produce a ton of logging (which you can disable). So those errors and warnings might not even matter. It will try to enhance all loaded classes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256092/discussion-between-ludov-dmitrii-and-m-deinum).

Comment: No, let us not continue the discussion in a chat, because SO is no discussion forum but a Q/A platform. The correct next step is for you to provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on GitHub, so we can reproduce your problem instead of relying on incomplete info snippets. Please note that I also beautified your code snippets above a bit and fixed your typo(?) "graddle" to correctly read Gradle in several places.

Comment: @kriegaex  The platform suggests to do so if comment section becomes like this. However you can act any way you like. If you can make a substantive solution - please. If only typo corrections are in your interests, thank you, appreciated your contribution.

Comment: I am aware of the fact that SO suggests that. It is a smell if that happens, not meant to incentivise long-winded debates. Being an AOP expert, my interest is to help you. That I fixed some cosmetical things in your question does not mean that it is my main interest. It was meant to be a free service to you, guiding you by example towards giving more love to your future questions. Being sloppy in small things as a developer (or in any job) means that those small things will add up to a big pile of mess eventually. Garbage in, garbage out.

Comment: So, if you want to do yourself a favour, provide the minimal, complete reproducer I suggested (not your full, possibly copyrighted project, just the smallest abstraction of it reproducing the problem at hand). Do that, and I will look into it. Don't and I won't. Spoiler: I am the current maintainer of AspectJ and know a thing or two about Spring AOP, too. As for M. Deinum, he is as insightful a Spring expert as you can get. If I cannot answer your question, he can for sure. A reproducer would help him as well. It is hard to reason about invisible code without a magical crystal globe.

Comment: @kriegaex well if you insist so much, be my guest https://github.com/lDummyl/dddservice.git

Comment: The application does not start: `Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured. Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class`. The test does not start either. Like this, I cannot help you. Please push an update which either makes it work without any DB or add an in-memory DB.

Comment: @kriegaex as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you run on JDK 16+. Maybe you forgot to add `--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED` as [documented in the AspectJ release notes](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/eclipse-aspectj/aspectj/blob/master/docs/dist/doc/README-1919.html) when trying to use the AspectJ weaver. Unfortunately, the [Spring manual chapter about using AspectJ](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/aop/using-aspectj.html) does not mention that.  Anyway, when I add that to the JVM command line in your example project and also activate `@EnableLoadTimeWeaving`, it works.

```java
package com.test.ddd;

import com.test.ddd.domain.wire.TestEnt;
import com.test.ddd.repo.TestRepo;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesScan;
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.EnableFeignClients;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableLoadTimeWeaving;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.aspectj.EnableSpringConfigured;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaAuditing;
import org.springframework.retry.annotation.EnableRetry;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;

import java.util.UUID;

@EnableRetry
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan
@EnableFeignClients
@EnableScheduling
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaAuditing
@EnableLoadTimeWeaving //goes with -javaagent:{full-path}spring-instrument-6.0.11.jar
@EnableSpringConfigured
public class DDDApplication {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(DDDApplication.class, args)) {
      TestRepo testRepo = context.getBean(TestRepo.class);
      testRepo.save(new TestEnt(UUID.randomUUID(), 1));
      testRepo.findAll().get(0).call();
    }
  }
}
```

```
--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED -javaagent:/my/path/spring-instrument-6.0.11.jar
```

[image: IntelliJ IDEA run config for class DDDApplication]

Running the application, the console log says:

```
2023-12-02T08:18:02.884+07:00  INFO 10888 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2023-12-02T08:18:03.880+07:00  INFO 10888 --- [           main] com.test.ddd.DDDApplication              : Started DDDApplication in 33.258 seconds (process running for 34.46)
Hibernate: select t1_0.id,t1_0.incr from test_ent t1_0 where t1_0.id=?
Hibernate: insert into test_ent (incr,id) values (?,?)
Hibernate: select t1_0.id,t1_0.incr from test_ent t1_0
testRepo = org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository@33880bed
```

How you can set that option for your test in Gradle or in an IDE running tests via Gradle, I do not know. I am a Maven guy.

Comment: Well it worked. 11 does not require this key. Spring boot now limits the initlzr to the choice of 17 or 21 versions of Java. I don’t like the numerous warnings and side errors (which can be suppressed as was said), obviously this requires setting up access and for this we need verbose plugins, which I hoped we could do without. It feels like this aspect is currently poorly developed in the framework. I will think twice before using this. Indicate the path(or mess with classpath) to jar and God knows what kind of pitfalls will be possible in the future if there will be mess in reflection tools.

Comment: Perhaps, after all, the path through custom LoadTimeWeaver, which was proposed in the exception message as an alternative to the Java Agent, will be more convenient in the current modern versions of the boot. But how to configure it is not yet clear.

Comment: Don't blame the framework. It is the JVM that has changed, introducing more and more new "security features", making tool development harder and harder. Just because you quickly judge something as "poorly developed", it does not mean it is. The JVM wants more explicit user decisions concerning what should be allowed to be done by tools. This is supposed to prevent hacks the user is unaware of. So just give permission, if it is what you want. Your complaints are not going to stop the JVM from developing.

Comment: By the way, you said my solution works. Then please, accept the answer.

Comment: My, as you call them, complains is simply an explanation of why I will not use this approach. I don’t need to set up spring bins via XML for a long time now. This is done easily and declaratively and does not require me to poke the framework’s nose into jars or say which packages to scan or classes to load. I am interested in a simple boxed solution, it is not available at the moment, from a learning point of view it is interesting and my gratitude is immeasurable. But I do not consider this as a suitable solution for the project, for which I am very sorry.

Comment: What does a Java agent on the JVM command line have to do with XML config? Let us not start comparing apples to pears, please. As for your wish to use a weaving agent without declaring same agent on the command line, please be informed that since JDK 21, dynamic attachment of agents without the user explicitly allowing it via command line flag has been prepared to be removed in the future., see [JEP 451](https://openjdk.org/jeps/451). I.e., in the future there will be no stealth mode agent attachment anymore, even though now there still are ways to achieve it. I suggest to get used to it now.

Comment: Setting a simple command line parameter like you also do for the class path, debug logging or other JVM or application features, is a reality you cannot just deny, magically wishing for a "simple boxed solution". What looks simple from the outside, might require lots of plumbing on the inside, and still not work reliably in every situation. If you do not like that prospect, maybe you want to consider using compile-time instead of load-time weaving.